# No icon for PrimeFaces checkboxed tree nodes in non-selecteable state?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, treenode

I am using PrimeFaces and I created a checkbox Tree.

Some nodes have no children, so I set them to not selectable:

```
    node.setSelectable( false);
```

The problem is, nodes that are not selectable show no checkbox at all. They have no icon for this "disabled" state. It's just empty space and doesn't look good.

Is this expected behaviour or am I missing something?

p.s.

[Screenshot here.](http://www.2shared.com/photo/6JxamxWY/PrimeFaces-disabled_tree_node_.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. Might be changed in future versions.